# "Unrecognized browser or device" email received from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Email I received from Facebook said:

> your account was recently logged into from an unrecognized browser or device.  Was this you?   May 16, 2017 @ 9:25 p.m.   Near Ranchito, Belize   IE on Windows.

Was this a legitimate email from Facebook?

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You got this email that means you have set **Get alerts about unrecognized logins** in *Security and Login Settings* section and have chosen to receive your alerts with your email account.

So when you or someone else login your account in a new browser (where you have never logged-in before or you have just cleared browsing history of known browser), Facebook sent an alert (through email or Facebook notification or both, depends on settings) to you to recognize the device.

This is a legitimate email from Facebook.

Here what you should do:

> - When you receive a login alert, you can tell us if you recognize the login activity by clicking or tapping **This was me**.
> - If you don't recognize the login activity, click or tap **This wasn't me** and we'll help you **reset your password** and secure your account.
> - You can save a device or browser to your list of trusted browsers or recognized devices. This way, you won't get alerts about the computer or mobile device you usually use to log into Facebook. Don't choose this option if you're using a public computer (such as one in a library or cafe).

Learn more about account security:
[How to get alerts about unrecognized logins](https://www.facebook.com/help/162968940433354)
[If you don’t recognize a location in the *Where You're Logged In* section of my Facebook account](https://www.facebook.com/help/224047177607864)
[How to log out of Facebook on another computer, phone or tablet](https://www.facebook.com/help/211990645501187)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a phishing attempt. DO NOT CLICK ANY LINKS WITHIN THE EMAIL!!

First, look at the return address of the email. I just received an email like yours, but the return address was: Facebook Security `<security@fbook-alerts.com>`. A quick whois lookup of fbook-alerts.com reveals that it is not a real domain! Strike one for this email!

Second, hover your mouse over the "Review Login" button. Don't click on it!! Look at the bottom left area of your browser window, where you will likely see link URL associated with the button. It might look like this, which is what my email contained:

`http://online-banking.kb4.io`... etc. etc. etc. lots of gibberish

See how the address in the link doesn't say anything about Facebook? And it says online-banking.kb4.io? A quick search on threatcrowd.org shows this as a malicious domain. Strike two!

That's enough strikes for me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Desire! I didn't catch the fact that I'd unintentionally created clickable links! Argh!

Answer (score 0):

this is only authenticated id you have enabled notification from your profile. Generally this is to inform user that someone is try to login your account.

Same kind of mail is generated by Gmail if your try to login from another device.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not click on anything in the mail. It could very well be spam. Delete it.
2. Do you have any reason to believe that that was a legitimate login? (*You are not saying anything about that*) Were you travelling, did you use a VPN, did you temporarily give someone your login info?
3. If it is not a legitimate login, and even if it is a fake email, you should immediately change your FB password. Just to be sure. **Use a good password and don't reuse passwords across services**.